# Head First C# exercise

Tags: c#, class

I came up with a different method while attempting to solve an exercise in the book "Head First C#" than the given solution.  I'm pretty new to C# and programming in general, and I want to understand if and why the book's method is better than mine.

I'll detail the problem, then provide their answer and my answer.  Please give me as detailed and as simple/understandable answer as you can!

> Create a program with an Elephant class.  Make two Elephant instances
>   and then swap the reference values that point to them, without getting
>   any Elephant instances garbage-collected.  Make a form (Windows Forms
>   Application) with 3 buttons.  The first button says "Lloyd", the
>   second says "Lucinda", and the third says "Swap".  Clicking on the
>   Lucinda button or the Lloyd button pops up a new window that displays
>   the message "My ears are (EarSize) inches tall."  The title of the
>   popup window is   "(Name) says...", with name being either Lucinda or
>   Lloyd.
>
> You are supposed to create the Elephant class with an integer field
>   called EarSize, and a string field called Name.  WhoAmI() is the
>   method that displays the popup message box.  Create two elephant
>   instances and a reference; the two Elephant fields are added to the
>   Form1 class and are named Lloyd and Lucinda.  They're initialized;
>
> ```
> lucinda = new Elephant() { Name = "Lucinda", EarSize = 33 }; lloyd =
> new Elephant() { Name = "Lloyd", EarSize = 40 };
> ```
>
> Make the Lloyd and Lucinda buttons work.  The Lloyd button calls
>   `lloyd.WhoAmI()` and the Lucinda button calls `lucinda.WhoAmI()`.
>
> Hook up the swap button.  Make the swap button exchange the two
>   references, so that when you click swap, the Lloyd and Lucinda
>   variables swap objects and a "Objects swapped" box is displayed.  The
>   first time you click Swap, if you click the Lucinda button the Lloyd
>   box should come up, and if you click the Lloyd button the Lucinda box
>   should come up.  If you click Swap again, when you click Lloyd or
>   Lucinda their regular box should come up as normal.  If you click the
>   swap button again, the objects switch again and... you get the idea.

HERE is the code that the book provides as the correct answer:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Elephant 
{
  public int EarSize;
  public string Name;

  public void WhoAmI()
  {
     MessageBox.Show("My ears are " + EarSize + " inches tall.", Name  + " says...");
  }
}
```

****************************NEW CLASS*****************************

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
  Elephant lucinda;
  Elephant lloyd;

  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    lucinda = new Elephant() { Name = "Lucinda", EarSize = 33 };
    lloyd = new Elephant() { Name = "Lloyd", EarSize = 40 };
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    lloyd.WhoAmI();
  }

  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    lucinda.WhoAmI();
  }

  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Elephant holder;
    holder = lloyd;
    lloyd = lucinda;
    lucinda = holder;
    MessageBox.Show("Objects Swapped");
  }
}
```

************************MY ANSWER BELOW*****************************

The code shown so far was the two classes that makeup the books correct solution.  I will now paste the solution that I came up with below here.  My Elephant class is the same as the book's, but my Form1 class is different, so I will just post the class that is different.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Elephant lucinda;
    Elephant lloyd;
    public int counter = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lucinda = new Elephant() { Name = "Lucinda", EarSize = 33 };
        lloyd = new Elephant() { Name = "Lloyd", EarSize = 40 };
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (counter % 2 == 1)
        {
            lucinda.WhoAmI();
        }
        else
        {
            lloyd.WhoAmI();
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (counter % 2 == 1)
        {
            lloyd.WhoAmI();
        }
        else
        {
            lucinda.WhoAmI();
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter += 1;
        MessageBox.Show("Objects Swapped");           
    }
}
```

Please, I would appreciate any insight into the differences between these methods,which is better, and why that's so.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so the reason your answer would be considered wrong is as follows:

The question specifically asks you to do this:

> Make two Elephant instances and then swap the reference values that point to them, without getting any Elephant instances garbage-collected

What you did was define a way to look up which elephant needs to be displayed, but you did not complete the objective of the assignment, which was specifically to swap the reference the objects pointed to.

In the answer they provided they did just that:

```
  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Elephant holder;
    holder = lloyd;
    lloyd = lucinda;
    lucinda = holder;
    MessageBox.Show("Objects Swapped");
  }
```

They actually swapped the variable references. The point of the assignment seems to be to show you that you must maintain a reference to each object or they will be garbage collected. If you did not swap the references as they did above with a `holder` variable then one of the references would have been garbage collected as nothing would have referenced it anymore.

This is an important concept in any managed programming language, as you must make sure you maintain your references or you will lose the variable to the garbage collector. In an unmanaged programming language you would have a memory leak if you didn't use `holder`.

The answer they provide is also a much more important concept to learn. There are infinite ways of doing what they asked, but if you do it in this way then you learn how to manage references to objects and don't have to scatter lookups everywhere, such as your `if (counter % 2 == 1)`. Imagine if instead of two references you had 10. Now you have to go change all that logic!

I hope that helps you understand the point of the question, and if you have any other questions let me know!